# Can I force the dialog draggable only inside the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

**html:**

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Past Issues">
    </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        height: 900,
        width:1200,
        modal: true,
});
```

The problem is currently the dialog can be drag to few more cm of the window area, is it possible to set the containment is the window? Or the default setting is already is containment : window? If yes, what is the root course of the problem? thanks.

Comment: the demo (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) constrains the dialog to the viewport. can you show us a broken example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Comment: can u please post your code in jsfiddle so that we can try and help

Comment: thanks, perharps it is my windows size is large than the actual screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, for demo I have used a `div` you can replace it with `window`

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        var vDlg = $(event.target).parent();
        var vCont = $('#main');   // for window use - $(window);
        vDlg.draggable("option", "containment", vCont).appendTo(vCont);
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", "center");
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8JBtk/)

Comment: You also need to [set the containment for the `resizable` widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401699/616460), or you'll still be able to cross the bounds when resizing.

Answer (score 2):

The default `containment` option passed to the draggable widget used by the dialog is indeed `document`, not `window`.

You can override this default by obtaining the dialog widget using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), then accessing its `uiDialog` member and modifying the draggable's `containment` option there:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    height: 900,
    width: 1200,
    modal: true
}).data("ui-dialog").uiDialog.draggable("option", "containment", "window");
```

Comment: You also need to [set the containment for the `resizable` widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401699/616460), or you'll still be able to cross the bounds when resizing.