# How to make sure that a jQueryUI-Dialog's "X"-Button stays on Screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Please consider the following CodePen: https://codepen.io/ChrisVomRhein/pen/yzBwaZ

When you click the button, a dialog with a huge amount of text is opened and

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog("option", "position", { 
    my: "right top", 
    at: "right top", 
    of: $(this) 
});
```

makes sure that it is positioned relative to the button. For the three buttons on the top, this works nicely. jQuery makes sure that the dialog stays on screen.

[image: jQuery UI Dialog Scenario 1]

Even for the top left button jQuery is smart enough to shift the dialog so that it stays on screen.

[image: jQuery UI Dialog Scenario 2]

However, as soon as I click one of the buttons positioned at the bottom, jQuery also shifts the dialog; upwards this time. The problem is that the X-button (that closes the dialog) is no longer reachable. Also, there is not Scrollbar showing up!

[image: jQuery UI Dialog Scenario 3]

Is there any way to force jQuery UI to make sure that the X is always inside the accessible area of the browser window? Or am I missing something very basic here?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14136647/519413) may help you

Comment: Hey Rory. That works nicely if your dialog somehow fits inside your viewport in the first place. But otherwise (in my scenario) this hack makes it even worse :-( Just fork the codepen and try it yourself: The original behaviour is the same as described above; and as soon as you start dragging the dialog it is shifted all the way up!

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the dialog is smaller than the window you can set his height by retrieving it with jquery and passing as a parameter like this:

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: $(window).height()* 0.9 });
```

In this case the height retrieved is from the window, but you can search for the container element or anything else you want your dialog fit in.
height is multiplied by 0.9 for make it a bit smaller than the page.

Using the css property overflow:auto you can make the scroll bar appear when the text is bigger than the dialog,

Look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEOXaP?editors=1000)

#### Edit

I understood the problem, so i changed the code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGNNZz)
With this solution i set the dialog size to the max dimension possible checking the max between the space to the top and to the bottom:

```
$(".opener").click(function() {
  //get the button position
  var pos = $(this).position();
  //max between top and bottom
  var h = Math.max($(window).height()* 0.9 - pos.top, pos.top * 0.9  );
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      position: { 
          my: "right top", 
          at: "left bottom", 
          of: $(this) 
       },
       autoOpen: false, 
       height: h
  });
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi nardu. That solves the problem for the bottom buttons, that is correct. However, as soon as you add more buttons (e.g. a row in the middle of the screen at ~50%), the problem is still there. I adjusted my pen accordingly. Give it a shot, and you'll see what I mean :-)