# jQuery UI - prevent resizing of dialog outside the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

**PROBLEM:**
When doing resize on dialog, I want to prevent it from going outside parent div `dialog-container`. For some reason `containment` is not working as I expected. What else can I try?

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="dialog-container">
  <div id="dialog">My dialog</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
                            autoOpen:true,
                            modal: false,
                            resizable: true,
                            draggable: true,
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            title: "Title",
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
            })
        }
    }).parent().draggable({
        containment: '#dialog-container'
    }).resizable({
        containment: '#dialog-container'
    });
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/4zfmbktr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would **STRONGLY** advise moving to a newer jQuery UI Library. I found a lot of strange issues with the jQuery UI 1.8.18 selected in your Fiddle.

One of the things I found was that it was ignoring `options` applied to the resizable. If you read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903649/how-do-i-set-the-containment-on-a-jquery-ui-dialog), it talks about how to set this option. Jump top the answer by Jason C. So that is where I started:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    title: "Title",
    open: function() {
      $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      })
    }
  });
  var ui = $("#dialog").closest(".ui-dialog");
  ui.draggable("option", "containment", '#dialog-container');
  ui.resizable("option", "containment", '#dialog-container');
});
```

This did not work. Draggable containment worked, but resize containment failed HARD. I blame 1.8.18. I might test this again with the modern 1.12.1 just to see.

This does not mean you cannot use 1.8.18, if you can't change your library, here is a work around. There are caveats here.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2vaf3dr5/39/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    title: "Title",
    open: function() {
      $('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click', function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      })
    }
  });
  var ui = $("#dialog").closest(".ui-dialog");
  ui.draggable("option", "containment", '#dialog-container');
  ui.resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w, se",
    minHeight: 150,
    minWidth: 150,
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      var contPos = $("#dialog-container").position();
      contPos.bottom = contPos.top + $("#dialog-container").height();
      contPos.right = contPos.left + $("#dialog-container").width();
      contPos.height = $("#dialog-container").height();
      contPos.width = $("#dialog-container").width();
      if (ui.position.top <= contPos.top) {
        ui.position.top = contPos.top + 1;
      }
      if (ui.position.left <= contPos.left) {
        ui.position.left = contPos.left + 1;
      }
      if (ui.size.height >= contPos.height) {
        ui.size.height = contPos.height - 7;
      }
      if (ui.size.width >= contPos.width) {
        ui.size.width = contPos.width - 7;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I stripped away the pre-configured resizable option in dialog and wrote out the options directly. Again, containment didn't work here, so I had to make my own custom resize logic. In the end, this does what you'd expect.

One of the oddities or caveats, is that it's reading mouse movement and will continue to do so even when the mouse has exceeded the boundaries. So the Top and Left stop... but the width and height continue to grow. I do not know why and you know where I will point the finger.

I did try switching your libraries and the resize is... a bit better. Still odd with height but not with width. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2vaf3dr5/44/

That should get you going, I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking your time to look into this. I have assembled new jsfiddle with updated jquery ui version on https://jsfiddle.net/wf6931mh/ but the problem remains. Resize now works correctly only for handle `se` but not for `n` (it will go beyond `#dialog-container`). I guess I will have to write similar resize function as you did. Thanks again, all the best!

Comment: @RhymeGuy the new fiddle does not contain the proper Resources. It has the old 1.8.16 theme CSS library and does not have any jQuery UI library.